# fix heap properity data structure in C

Tags: c, data-structures, heap

I'm trying to write a function that restores the heap property . But all the time I come out bad results .

```
void fixHeap(int heapSize, struct Edge* edgeArray, int i){//edgeArray is our heap-array.
    int leftSon = leftSonIndex(i);
    int rightSon = rightSonIndex(i);
    int change;
    if((leftSon <= heapSize) && (edgeArray[i].cost < edgeArray[leftSon].cost)){
        change = leftSon;
    }else{
        change = i;
        if((rightSon <= heapSize) && (edgeArray[change].cost < edgeArray[rightSon].cost)){
            change = rightSon;
        }
    }

    if(change != i){
        swap(edgeArray, i, change);
        i = change;

        fixHeap(heapSize, edgeArray, i);
    }

}
```

Comment: for example, data 6, 4 , 4 , 5, 7, 2 arranged in
7 4 4 6 5 2

Comment: A common mistake when pushing a value down a heap (as opposed to a heap-up) is a failure to detect when *either* child is larger, and choosing the *larger* of the two children to perform the swap against and the subsequent branch to continue down. I suggest you verify you're doing that correctly. Your code appears to favor a "if left is larger always take that branch" approach, when in fact, right be be an even better candidate.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that if you choose the `leftSon` as the `change` in the first `if` block, then you don't compare it with `rightSon` to check if `rightSon` > `leftSon`.
Hence your example would fail in cases like this -:

```
  5
 / \
6   7
```

This is how it should be -:

```
void fixHeap( int heapSize, struct Edge* edgeArray, int i ) //edgeArray is our heap-array.
{
    int leftSon = leftSonIndex( i );
    int rightSon = rightSonIndex( i );
    int change = i;

    if ( ( leftSon <= heapSize ) && ( edgeArray[change].cost < edgeArray[leftSon].cost ) )
    {
        change = leftSon;
    }
    if ( ( rightSon <= heapSize ) && ( edgeArray[change].cost < edgeArray[rightSon].cost ) )
    {
        change = rightSon;
    }
    if ( change != i )
    {
        swap( edgeArray, i, change );
        fixHeap( heapSize, edgeArray, change );
    }
}
```